# Is it possible to group namespaces in one file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have more than 10 files (Views) which many of them use common namespaces (almost 5-6 at number).

It's difficult to manage namespaces for all files and I thought at grouping namespaces in one file and insert that file in each View, means one line instead of 5-6 lines of namespace.

How to do that ?

With Partial View, I guess that is not possible. What is the good way to group namespaces in one file ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add namespaces to your web.config under `system.web/pages/namespaces`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx

```xml
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.SomeNamespace" />
       </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Adding them here has the effect of adding these namespaces to all pages/views.